# twitter4j setpage() not working

Tags: java, twitter4j

I'm using twitter4j version 2.2.5.  `setPage()` doesn't seem to work if I use it with `setSince()` and `setUntil()`.  See the following code:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
int page = 1;
while(true) {
    Query query = new Query("from:someUser");
    query.setSince("2012-01-01");
    query.setUntil("2012-07-05");
    query.setRpp(100);
    query.setPage(page++);
    QueryResult qr = twitter.search(query);
    List<twitter4j.Tweet> qrTweets = qr.getTweets();
    if(qr.getTweets().size() == 0) break;
    for(twitter4j.Tweet t : qrTweets) {
        System.out.println(t.getId() + " " + t.getText());
    }
}
```

The code inside the loop is only executed once if I use `setSince()` and `setUntil()` methods.  But without them, `setPage()` seems to work and I get more tweet results.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that no tweets returned is greater than 100

Comment: I just learned that you cannot get tweets created over 1 week before if you use Query.  Interestingly enough, setRpp() doesn't seem to be working right.  If the user has a total of 80 tweets in the past week, and I set rpp=40, the query still returns all 80 tweets.  Have you encountered this as well Abhishek?

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be working for me. It only returns tweets from the past nine days, but that's expected (approximately) according to your comment.

You mentioned in the question that the loop only ran once with `rpp=100`, and you said in a comment that all 80 of the user's tweets were returned when `rpp=40`.  I think that would indicate that the code is working as expected.  If the user only has 80 tweets, the loop only should run once when `rpp=100`, and it should execute twice and display all their tweets when `rpp=40`.  Try displaying the page number as soon as you enter the while loop so you can see how many times the loop runs.